# Can photons also work as a catalyst?

Tags: reaction-mechanism

A lot of biological reactions need photons to work, like photosynthesis and making vitamin D in our skin. But are there any chemical reactions where photons are really just a catalyst so they are absorbed and emitted the same as the came? Or is there always a change in frequency/wavelength involved which implies perhaps that the photon is 'used'. Or is perhaps the use of the word catalyst in case of photons not very appropriate?

Comment: There is a phenomenon called [stimulated emission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stimulated_emission) which is used in lasers and which pretty well could have been an example you look for, had not the definition of a catalyst been assumed to include only substances. (Also, it is not a chemical reaction anyway.)

Answer (score 3):

I do not feel that the word catalyst applies to photochemistry.

Photochemistry allows to access much *higher energy* states and thus reach reaction pathways that are otherwise not possible. Photons do not stabilize transition states (how would you rationalize the interaction?).

Catalysts on the other hand are focused on lowering barriers so that reactions proceed via *lower energy* transition states.

Because catalysts only affect the transition states, catalysts cannot affect the equilibrium position of a reaction. For example, if you had a catalyst that allowed easier conversion between (*E*)- and (*Z*)- double bonds, you could not use the catalyst to selectively provide the one that is less favorable.

On the other hand, with photochemistry, we do not establish an equilibrium because the higher energy state is not necessarily accessible via microscopic reversibility. And indeed, we can selectively use photochemistry to provide the less favorable species as is well know in the [case of stilbenes](https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/virttxtjml/photchem.htm).

EDIT:

Thanks to airhuff for pointing out that the requirement that a catalyst not be consumed also implies that we should not think about photons as catalysts. Hard to imagine a situation where you would absorb a photon and release one that is the same energy...

Comment: It's also hard to imagine a photon participating in a chemical reaction without being consumed, or a reaction where another photon of the same energy is re-emitted, which would be required for the photon to truly be a catalyst.